# Checking is not null in where condition

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am looking for some way of implementing the following part:

```sql
...
where JSON_SEARCH(content, 'one', 'XXX', NULL, "$.lib.books[*].id") is not null;
```

with JOOQ. Currently I have:

```java
...
   .where(EVENT.SENDERID.eq(userId)
        .and(DSL.condition("JSON_SEARCH({0}, 'one', {1}', NULL, \"\$.lib.books[*].id\")", BOOK.CONTENT, DSL.`val`(bookId, BOOK.CONTENT))))
```

but can't figure out how to apply this `is not null` condition which is required by `JSON_SEARCH` [itself](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_search/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`DSL.condition(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-java.lang.String-) which produces a condition / predicate, not a column reference. What you want is [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-):

```java
.where(EVENT.SENDERID.eq(userId)
    .and(DSL.field("JSON_SEARCH({0}, 'one', {1}', NULL, \"\$.lib.books[*].id\")", 
             BOOK.CONTENT, 
             DSL.`val`(bookId, BOOK.CONTENT)).isNotNull() ))
```